# How to use apply for two pandas column including lists to return index in a list in one column using the element in another column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply, python-applymap

I have a pandas Dataframe with columns of "a" and "b". Column a has a list of values as a column value,  and column "b" has a list with a single value that might appear in column "a". I want to create a new column c based on column a and b that has the value of position of element in b that appears in column a values using apply. (c: (index of b in a)+1 )
column b is always a list with one element or no element at all, column a can be in any length, but if it is empty, column b would be empty as well. column b element is expected to be in column a and I just want to find the position of first occurrence of it in column a.

```
a                         b                   c 


['1', '2', '5']          ['2']                2

['2','3','4']            ['4']                3
['2','3','4']            []                   0
[]                       []                   0
...
```

I wrote a for loop which works fine but it is pretty slow:

```
for i in range(0,len(df)):

    if len(df['a'][i])!=0:
        df['c'][i]=df['a'][i].index(*df['b'][i])+1 
    else:
        df['c'][i]=0
```

But I want to use apply to make it faster, the following does not work, any thoughts or suggestion would greatly be appreciated?

```
df['c']=df['a'].apply(df['a'].index(*df['b']))
```

Comment: Are all the lists the same size? Where does your DataFrame come from? We might need more of your code, maybe some sample data. See: [mcve].

Comment: Also, why do you want your results in one-based indexing? Your code creates a column `’d’`, but you make no mention of it in your explanations.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning it, column d is just to count the numbers of times that element in b appears in column a, but If i figure out how to create column c, I could do the same thing for column d as well, that is why I did not mention anything about it.

Comment: Alright, that makes sense. I’ll take a look at this tomorrow, I’m sure we can find a good solution. In the meantime, do add more details if you think of anything, eh. The format of your DataFrame, and the surrounding code, can drastically change which solution is best.

Comment: Thank you, I will add more detail in the meantime to make it more clear.

Comment: In column ‘b’, there is an empty list. Is that intended, or a typo?

Comment: column b can either be empty or hold one element, it is not a typo.

Comment: Column ‘a’ can contain empty lists as well? What happens if the list column ‘b’ is empty? Are there any patterns to this whole thing?

Comment: Also, I don’t believe you ever explained why you’re using one-based indexing. Again, some more context for this problem would be good.

Comment: column b is always a list with one element or no element at all, column a can be in any length, but if it is empty, column b would be empty as well. column b element is expected to be in column a and I just want to find the position of first occurrence of it in column a. (I want to find why specific customer end up buying the item listed in column b and where for the first time the customer viewed the item that he bought, hope it helps)

Comment: Are columns ‘a’ and ‘b’ the only two in your DataFrame? There has to be a better way to do things than by storing lists in a DataFrame, right?

Comment: I have lots of columns in my dataframe and I am trying to do feature engineering to give more structure to it, that is why I am doing the following here and I thought there should be a simpler apply function to use in this case instead of for loop which is super slow.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202751/discussion-between-alexander-cecile-and-mojgan-mazouchi).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, here is a basic method using `.apply()`.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

list_a = [['1', '2', '5'], ['2', '3', '4'], ['2', '3', '4'], []]
list_b = [['2'], ['4'], [], []]

df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data=zip(list_a, list_b), columns=['a', 'b'])

df_1['a'] = df_1['a'].map(lambda x: x if x else np.NaN)
df_1['b'] = df_1['b'].map(lambda x: x[0] if x else np.NaN)
#df_1['b'] = df_1['b'].map(lambda x: next(iter(x), np.NaN))


def calc_c(curr_row: pd.Series) -> int:
    if curr_row['a'] is np.NaN or curr_row['b'] is np.NaN:
        return 0
    else:
        return curr_row['a'].index(curr_row['b'])


df_1['c'] = df_1[['a', 'b']].apply(func=calc_c, axis=1)
```

`df_1` result:

```
    a                  b    c
--  ---------------  ---  ---
 0  ['1', '2', '5']    2    1
 1  ['2', '3', '4']    4    2
 2  ['2', '3', '4']  nan    0
 3  nan              nan    0
```

I replaced the empty lists with `NaN`, I find it far more idiomatic and practical.

This is obviously not an ideal solution, I will try to find something else. Obviously, the more information we have about your program and the DataFrame, the better.

Comment: This helped me with another pattern i was looking at, thanks Alexander, this is a great answer +1

Comment: @oppressionslayer If it isn't too much of a hassle, could you share the pattern? I'm curious :)

Comment: I had trouble figuring out how to dynamically deal with columns in apply functions, but now i see i can get them as keys (from curr_row) dict_keys({"a":["1","2","5"],"c":1}) #-->   dict_keys(['a', 'c'])  so now i can make better apply functions  in general. A lot of questions on pandas that don't get answered seem to be because there missing a magic one liner, but with dynamic column apply functions i think i can make some good answers for questions I wasn't able to before

Comment: And i didn't know you could structure the function that way, so that helps tremendously. I'll probably have a few questions for you in the future

Comment: @oppressionslayer Yeah, when used on rows (which you indicate with axis=1, I always forget), your function receives Series. `.apply()` is a great function, it shouldn't be your first choice, but when all other options fail, it just works.

Comment: @oppressionslayer Forgot to add that questions are always welcome <3 :)

Comment: Thank you @AlexanderCécile! It worked like a charm!

Comment: @MojganMazouchi Everything was clear? Any questions?

Comment: Yes, crystal clear, and it runs great and much faster than the for loop that I had in place. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

By reading in the data so the data types are list, i am able to create an apply function that creates the values for c:

```
import io, ast

#a b
#['1','2','5'] ['2']
#['2','3','4'] ['4']
#['2','3','4'] []
#[] []

csvfile=io.StringIO("""a b
['1','2','5'] ['2']
['2','3','4'] ['4']
['2','3','4'] []
[] []""")

df = pd.read_csv(csvfile, sep=' ', converters={'a' : ast.literal_eval, 'b' : ast.literal_eval }) 

def a_b_index(hm):
  if hm.b != []:
     return hm.a.index(hm.b[0])
  else:
     return 0

df['c'] = df.apply(a_b_index, axis=1)

df.c
#           a    b  c
#0  [1, 2, 5]  [2]  1
#1  [2, 3, 4]  [4]  2
#2  [2, 3, 4]   []  0
#3         []   []  0
```

Comment: Is `eval()` _really_ the best choice here?

Comment: pandas was seeing the data type as an object that i couldn't convert so i opted for eval. Until, i can figure out how to convert them without eval, this is the best way i could figure out how to accomplish this goal. I keep a text file for all of my Pandas patterns and modify them when i have better answers

Comment: I changed how this works, the apply function now doesn't eval, but we do read the lists in as eval. Another suggestion to me was using .apply(eval) for the solution, so that may be an option as well.

Comment: How would you use `eval()` for the operation itself?

Comment: If you read it in the data the way i do, i couldn't figure out how else to get a list with eval. I'm expanding my knowledge on pandas apply functions, your answer has helped me in this area.  This is what i love about stackoverflow, continuously learning new things and building better patterns for my library